# В android приложении значение в полях сохраняются при перезаходе на экран, хотя не должны. Как это исправить?

Tags: java, android, android-fragment, android-textview

В android studio у меня есть фильтры поиска в приложении, и при выходе с фрагмента с ними на другой фрагмент, и возврате обратно, значение в полях с фильтрами сохраняются, хотя в коде нигде нету переносов их между экранами.
Вот код меню с фильтрами:

```
showFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    Pair<ArrayList<String>, Integer> cityListGetResult = objectDataExchange.cityListGet(getContext(), sharedPreferences.getLong("id", 0));
                    if (cityListGetResult.second != null) {
                        toastCreator.createToast(getContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[cityListGetResult.second]);
                        return;
                    }
                    else {
                        cities.addAll(cityListGetResult.first);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }
                cities.add(getContext().getString(R.string.ObjectCityFilterEdit));
                ArrayAdapter<String> citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.city_dropdown_item, cities) {
                    @Override
                    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                        View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                        if (position == getCount()) {
                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                            ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(cities.get(getCount())); //"Hint to be displayed"
                        }

                        return v;
                    }

                    @Override
                    public int getCount() {
                        return super.getCount()-1; // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
                    }
                };
                cityFilterSpinner.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
                cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getPosition(filters.get("city")));
                //mainActivity.getProfileBtn().setVisibility(View.GONE);
                filtersCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                closeFiltersBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                clearFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getCount());
                        addressIndexFilterEdit.setText(null);
                        filters.replace("addressIndex", getContext().getString(R.string.ObjectCityFilterEdit));
                        filters.replace("city", null);
                    }
                });
                closeFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        filtersCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        closeFiltersBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Код перехода между фрагментами:

```
ListOfWorkersFragment listOfWorkersFragment = new ListOfWorkersFragment();
ChangePasswordFragment changePasswordFragment = new ChangePasswordFragment();
</code>
Код перехода на фрагмент с фильтрами:
<code lang="java">
ListOfObjectsBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    if (roleModel.HaveAccess(context, "***url***")) {
                        Pair<Company, Integer> getCompanyResult = companyDataExchange.CompanyDataGetByUser(getApplicationContext());
                        if (getCompanyResult.first != null) {
                            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutMain);
                            String tag = currentFragment.getTag();
                            menuController.changeFragment(tag, "listofobjects");
                            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayoutMain, listOfObjectsFragment, "listofobjects");
                            ft.commit();
                        }
                        else if (getCompanyResult.first == null && getCompanyResult.second == null) {
                            toastCreator.createToast(getApplicationContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[15]);
                        }
                        else if (getCompanyResult.first == null && getCompanyResult.second != null) {
                            toastCreator.createToast(getApplicationContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[getCompanyResult.second]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }
        });
```

Код перехода на другой фрагмент:

```
ListOfWorkersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                try {
                    if (roleModel.HaveAccess(context, "***url***")) {
                        Pair<Company, Integer> getCompanyResult = companyDataExchange.CompanyDataGetByUser(getApplicationContext());
                        if (getCompanyResult.first != null) {
                            Fragment currentFragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frameLayoutMain);
                            String tag = currentFragment.getTag();
                            menuController.changeFragment(tag, "listofworkers");
                            FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                            ft.replace(R.id.frameLayoutMain, listOfWorkersFragment, "listofworkers");
                            ft.commit();
                        }
                        else if (getCompanyResult.first == null && getCompanyResult.second == null) {
                            toastCreator.createToast(getApplicationContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[15]);
                        }
                        else if (getCompanyResult.first == null && getCompanyResult.second != null) {
                            toastCreator.createToast(getApplicationContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[getCompanyResult.second]);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(e);
                }

            }
        });
```

Что сделать, чтобы значения не сохранялись?

Answer (score 0):

Мне помогло такое изменение кода меню с фильтрами:

```
showFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            ArrayList<String> cities = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                Pair<ArrayList<String>, Integer> cityListGetResult = objectDataExchange.cityListGet(getContext(), sharedPreferences.getLong("id", 0));
                if (cityListGetResult.second != null) {
                    toastCreator.createToast(getContext(), getLayoutInflater(), getResources().getStringArray(R.array.errors)[cityListGetResult.second]);
                    return;
                }
                else {
                    cities.addAll(cityListGetResult.first);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
            cities.add(getContext().getString(R.string.ObjectCityFilterEdit));
            ArrayAdapter<String> citiesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(), R.layout.city_dropdown_item, cities) {
                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (position == getCount()-1) {
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setText("");
                        ((TextView)v.findViewById(android.R.id.text1)).setHint(cities.get(getCount()-1)); //"Hint to be displayed"
                    }

                    return v;
                }

                @Override
                public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
                    View v = super.getDropDownView(position, convertView, parent);
                    if (position == getCount()-1) {
                        return new View(getContext());
                    }
                    return v;
                }

                @Nullable
                @Override
                public String getItem(int position) {
                    return position != getCount() - 1 ? super.getItem(position) : "";
                }

                @Override
                public int getCount() {
                    return super.getCount(); // you dont display last item. It is used as hint.
                }
            };
            filtersCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            closeFiltersBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cityFilterSpinner.setAdapter(citiesAdapter);
            cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getCount()-1);
            addressIndexFilterEdit.setText(null);
            cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getPosition(filters.get("city")));
            addressIndexFilterEdit.setText(filters.get("addressIndex"));
            //mainActivity.getProfileBtn().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            clearFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getCount());
                    addressIndexFilterEdit.setText(null);
                    filters.replace("addressIndex", getContext().getString(R.string.ObjectCityFilterEdit));
                    filters.replace("city", null);
                }
            });
            closeFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    filtersCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    closeFiltersBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            });
            applyFiltersBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    filters.replace("addressIndex", addressIndexFilterEdit.getText().toString());
                    filters.replace("city", cityFilterSpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
                    cityFilterSpinner.setSelection(citiesAdapter.getCount());
                    addressIndexFilterEdit.setText(null);
                    filtersCard.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    closeFiltersBtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    ShowObjects(searchPlain.getText().toString(), linear, sharedPreferences, ft);
                    //mainActivity.getProfileBtn().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```